# vue-ctk-date-time-picker 2 how to change drop down position to right?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

hi i'm using vueCtkDateTimePicker in my project and couldn't change dropdown position to right

```
                <vue-ctk-date-time-picker
                    v-model="task.DueDate"
                    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                    :only-date="true"
                    :position="'right'"
                    :noLabel="true"
                ></vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
```

i've tried many word combinations with and without binding but nothing works. couldn't find an explanation in documentation either.

Comment: never mind found the solution just <vue-ctk-date-time-picker
                        v-model="runningReport.task.DueDate"
                        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                        right
                        :only-date="true"
                        :noLabel="true"
                    ></vue-ctk-date-time-picker>

Answer (score 1):

never mind found it just use 'right' as a prop

```
              <vue-ctk-date-time-picker
                    v-model="runningReport.task.DueDate"
                    format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                    right
                    :only-date="true"
                    :noLabel="true"
                ></vue-ctk-date-time-picker>
```